# NHibernate ICriteria API: Retrievieng two objects without foreign key linking

Tags: .net, nhibernate, icriteria

Due to architectural considerations (separation into aggregates) I use the aggregate A which has a B_Id to entity B which should not be part of the A-aggregate.

The attribute B_Id of A is simply mapped in NHibernates XML as follows:

```
<property name="B_Id" />
```

I like to code a query with ICriteria API which should express this SQL Query:

> SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.B_Id = b.Id

The problem is now: The B_Id is not mapped as a foreign key (and should not).

Are there solutions to retrieve all attributes of A and B in one query regenerated by ICriteria?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by mapping the relationship using a [query only property](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/10/nhibernate-ndash-query-only-properties.aspx). You can also do it using [HQL's with clause](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/05/17/nhibernate-2-1-0-hql-with-clause.aspx) but (as far as I know) that doesn't support left outer joins. I don't know if any way to do it using the Criteria API.